# Storing all the results from a FOR LOOP in an array

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, random

I have created an array called Player1_Cards.
Each card needs to have a number and a colour.
Player1 should have 15 cards, which can be numbered from 1 to 30.

I have used a for loop to do this:

using random.randint (1,30), I have found the number of the card.

using random.randint(1,3), I allocate number 1,2 or 3 to colours RED, YELLOW or BLACK.

How do I store all my results from the for loop as an array?

Here is my code:

```
Player1_Cards = [0]

import random
for i in range(1,16):
    i = random.randint(1,30)
    i_colour = random.randint(1,3)
    i_colour = str(i_colour)

    if i_colour == "1":
        i_colour = "RED"

    if i_colour == "2":
        i_colour = "YELLOW"

    if i_colour == "3":
        i_colour = "BLACK"



    Player1_Cards[i,i_colour]
```

If I print(i,i_colour), ignoring the array, examples of what it may execute is:

```
6 YELLOW
28 YELLOW
8 RED
3 BLACK
22 RED
2 BLACK
26 RED
25 YELLOW
8 RED
20 RED
16 BLACK
12 YELLOW
4 RED
20 BLACK
1 YELLOW
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to implement this is using list comprehensions:

```
import random

colours = ['RED', 'BLUE', 'YEllOW']
player_hand = [(random.randint(1, 30), random.choice(colours)) for _ in range(15)]

Output:
# 21 BLUE
# 22 BLUE
# 25 YEllOW
# 11 BLUE
# 4 RED
...
```

Comment: Just a little nitpicking: since `i` isn't used, maybe `for _ in range(1, 16)` would be better (also, notice `range(1, 16)` instead of `range(16)`, it's not the same thing!).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Player1_Cards = []
```

in the beginning.  then at the end of the loop:

```
Player1_Cards.append((i, i_colour))
```

And after the loop:

```
print(Player1_Cards)
```

You also have a bug in your code:

```
for i in range(1,16):
    i = random.randint(1,30)
```

Both will set the variable `i` to a value.  It doesn't make sense this way.  If you just want to do your loop fifteen times, better use the `_` instead:

```
for _ in range(1,16):
```

Comment: Ah thank you, much appreciated it. Also, how could you ensure that player1's cards are not the same as player2's cards?

Comment: I propose to take player1's card _out of the deck_ before drawing player2's.  Do this like you would in real life:  Create a deck of all cards, shuffle the deck, then take the top _n_ for player 1, afterwards take the top _m_ for player 2.

Comment: `deck = list(range(52))` (for a poker deck), `random.shuffle(deck)`, `player1cards = deck[0:12]`, `player2cards = deck[12:24]`.  You then have to interpret the mere numbers as cards, e. g. like this: `suit = card % 4`, `value = card / 4`, `VALUE_NAMES = [ '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A' ]` and use `VALUE_NAMES[value]` to get the name of the value of the card.